# I've built an express js app. When I load a page I always have to refresh for varibles to display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

Hope you can help me. I have searched for an answer but haven't been able to find one.

I have built an app in Express.js that has a simple form in jade. It should display "Yes" if the database is connected.

The page will load and display nothing. If I then Ctrl-R or refresh the value I was expecting will appear correctly.

How do I make it so it automatically appears without refreshing..?

Cheers and thank you,

Matt

index.jade

```
p Connected to DB?:
    if locals.connected
    p= connected
```

index.js (routed to via app.js -> routes.js -> index.js

```
Var connected;    
function listCollections() {
      mongoose.connection.on('open', function () {
        connected = "Yes";
});
}


exports.init = function(req, res, next){
  listCollections();
  res.render('./index', {
     connected:connected
   });
}
};
```

Routes.js

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.set('X-Auth-Required', 'true');
  req.session.returnUrl = req.originalUrl;
  res.redirect('/login/');
}

function ensureAdmin(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user.canPlayRoleOf('admin')) {
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect('/');
}

function ensureAccount(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user.canPlayRoleOf('account')) {
    if (req.app.config.requireAccountVerification) {
      if (req.user.roles.account.isVerified !== 'yes' && !/^\/account\/verification\//.test(req.url)) {
        return res.redirect('/account/verification/');
      }
    }
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect('/');
}
exports = module.exports = function(app, passport) {
  app.all('/*', ensureAuthenticated);
  app.all('/*', ensureAccount);
  //product
  app.get('/', require('./views/index').init);
  app.post('/', require('./views/index').init);


};
```

Comment: can you show your route configuration?

Comment: Hi, yes I will add it to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its asynchronous, the page gets render before your connection gets established. you should do something like this.

```
       function listCollections(callback) {
            mongoose.connection.on('open', function () {
                callback("Yes"); // render callback gets invoke after connection
            });
        }


        exports.init = function(req, res, next){
            listCollections(function(connected){ // passing render as callback
                res.render('./index', {
                    connected:connected
                });
            });
        }
```